# wix toolset bootsrap exe hangs on start

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.5

trying to make an installer wit multi language support, i know i have to use a boostrapper. But when i wanted to make a test file, it will freeze.

My main is just a simple form that will display a "hello world" text.
The SetupProject is also the basic XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="cbb7c280-e909-4a3c-9aab-76f6a4cc75e5">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="ProductComponent">
                <File Source="$(var.cs_tt10_bundle.TargetPath)" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The Bootsrapper file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="e7d3169f-9d31-4849-b75d-567c796b19f8">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.SetupProject.TargetPath)" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

When i compile everything i get the .exe but when i try to run it, it hangs.
No process explorer can close it. It locks the file and the only way (i know) to "kill" the program is restarting the machine.

I have no idea how to debug the bootstrapper...

Comment: if you are gonna install only one MSI package, there is no need to create exe using Burn.

Comment: any way to make an msi multi language other than bootstrapping?

Comment: you can read it here [Wix Tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/localization/)

Comment: "This localization project is no longer active." Also, i can use any other language, but only one of them at a time, for example, i want to make an installer that will present hu-hu on a Hungarian system, and en-Us for the rest of the world. Sadly, [this](http://www.geektieguy.com/2010/03/13/create-a-multi-lingual-multi-language-msi-using-wix-and-custom-build-scripts/) is outdated.